# extracting strings lead to empty strings in RegEx

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have the following file:

```
awk -F'\t' '$3=="mRNA"'  GCF_000390325.2_Ntom_v01_genomic.gff | head
NW_008828495.1  Gnomon  mRNA    35293   38211   .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_009608413.3;Parent=gene-LOC104084433;Dbxref=GeneID:104084433,Genbank:XM_009608413.3;Name=XM_009608413.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104084433;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 6 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 76 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=cytochrome P450 CYP82D47-like;transcript_id=XM_009608413.3
NW_008828515.1  Gnomon  mRNA    6799    11530   .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_009591409.3;Parent=gene-LOC104116524;Dbxref=GeneID:104116524,Genbank:XM_009591409.3;Name=XM_009591409.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104116524;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 2 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 22 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X2;transcript_id=XM_009591409.3
NW_008828515.1  Gnomon  mRNA    6799    11530   .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_009630598.3;Parent=gene-LOC104116524;Dbxref=GeneID:104116524,Genbank:XM_009630598.3;Name=XM_009630598.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104116524;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 2 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 34 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X1;transcript_id=XM_009630598.3
NW_008828528.1  Gnomon  mRNA    2303    14453   .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_033657931.1;Parent=gene-LOC117278374;Dbxref=GeneID:117278374,Genbank:XM_033657931.1;Name=XM_033657931.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC117278374;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 72%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments;product=uncharacterized LOC117278374;transcript_id=XM_033657931.1
NW_008828528.1  Gnomon  mRNA    5510    7652    .   -   .   ID=rna-XM_033657569.1;Parent=gene-LOC117278090;Dbxref=GeneID:117278090,Genbank:XM_033657569.1;Name=XM_033657569.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC117278090;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 1 sample with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized mitochondrial protein AtMg00810-like%2C transcript variant X1;transcript_id=XM_033657569.1
NW_008828528.1  Gnomon  mRNA    5873    8848    .   -   .   ID=rna-XM_033657711.1;Parent=gene-LOC117278090;Dbxref=GeneID:117278090,Genbank:XM_033657711.1;Name=XM_033657711.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC117278090;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 2 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized mitochondrial protein AtMg00810-like%2C transcript variant X2;transcript_id=XM_033657711.1
NW_008828570.1  Gnomon  mRNA    5   6611    .   -   .   ID=rna-XM_009610342.3;Parent=gene-LOC104102329;Dbxref=GeneID:104102329,Genbank:XM_009610342.3;Name=XM_009610342.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104102329;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 27 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 56 samples with support for all annotated introns;partial=true;product=TATA-box-binding protein-like;start_range=.,5;transcript_id=XM_009610342.3
NW_008828592.1  Gnomon  mRNA    9998    13370   .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_033658453.1;Parent=gene-LOC104103684;Dbxref=GeneID:104103684,Genbank:XM_033658453.1;Name=XM_033658453.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104103684;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 3 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 10 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=pentatricopeptide repeat-containing protein At1g15510%2C chloroplastic;transcript_id=XM_033658453.1
NW_008828592.1  Gnomon  mRNA    13457   18285   .   -   .   ID=rna-XM_009612846.3;Parent=gene-LOC104104451;Dbxref=GeneID:104104451,Genbank:XM_009612846.3;Name=XM_009612846.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104104451;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 Protein%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 23 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=uncharacterized LOC104104451;transcript_id=XM_009612846.3
NW_008828641.1  Gnomon  mRNA    4417    7406    .   +   .   ID=rna-XM_009613787.3;Parent=gene-LOC104105226;Dbxref=GeneID:104105226,Genbank:XM_009613787.3;Name=XM_009613787.3;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC104105226;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 8 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 75 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=heat shock factor protein HSF30%2C transcript variant X1;transcript_id=XM_009613787.3
```

I used the below commnand to extract `ID,product` values but I only got `.mrna1,`

```
awk -F'\t' '$3=="mRNA"'  GCF_000390325.2_Ntom_v01_genomic.gff | perl -F'\t' -lane 'if($F[2] eq "mRNA"){/ID=([^\;]+).*product="([^"]+)/; print "$1.mrna1,$2"}' > GCF_000390325.2_Ntom_v01_genomic.gff.csv
```

As output I would like to get:

```
rna-XM_009608413.3,cytochrome P450 CYP82D47-like
rna-XM_009591409.3,protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X2
rna-XM_009630598.3,protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X1
rna-XM_033657931.1,uncharacterized LOC117278374
rna-XM_033657569.1,uncharacterized mitochondrial protein AtMg00810-like%2C transcript variant X1
...
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use the capture variables $1 $2 erc we must make sure before that they exist.

In this case the $1 $2 are empty and since you have warnings not turned ON so you don't get informed about it.

Note that your regex is expecting a quote after product= "while in your data there are no quotes. I suggest you invoke perl with -w option.

```
perl  -w -F'\t' -lane 'if(($F[2] eq "mRNA")&&/ID=([^\;]+).*product=([^;]+)/){print "$1.mrna1,$2"}'
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only get the first world:  `rna-XM_009608413.3.mrna1,cytochrome` instead of `rna-XM_009608413.3.mrna1,cytochrome P450 CYP82D47-like`

Comment: See my updated answer. Don't forget to turn ON the warnings - w option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pipe to/use `perl`.  It can all be done by `awk`.

```
$ awk  -F'[\t;]' '{for(i=11; i < NF;i++) if($i ~ /^product=/) { sub(/ID=/,"",$9); sub(/^product=/, "", $i); print $9","$i }}' infile
rna-XM_009608413.3,cytochrome P450 CYP82D47-like
rna-XM_009591409.3,protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X2
rna-XM_009630598.3,protein JASON-like%2C transcript variant X1
rna-XM_033657931.1,uncharacterized LOC117278374
rna-XM_033657569.1,uncharacterized mitochondrial protein AtMg00810-like%2C transcript variant X1
rna-XM_033657711.1,uncharacterized mitochondrial protein AtMg00810-like%2C transcript variant X2
rna-XM_009610342.3,TATA-box-binding protein-like
rna-XM_033658453.1,pentatricopeptide repeat-containing protein At1g15510%2C chloroplastic
rna-XM_009612846.3,uncharacterized LOC104104451
rna-XM_009613787.3,heat shock factor protein HSF30%2C transcript variant X1
$
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for rna-`XM_009610342.3` because it has `partial` in between.

Comment: @user977828.  I have updated my answer to reflect the new information supplied by you.